# How to remove the date from time data when it is separated by a space?

Tags: python, csv, time, spyder

I have some data in a current .csv file that is space separated then ; separated. I get how to do the sep";" but the problem is the spaces. It looks a little like this:

```
Time; Age; etc
04-09-2003 17:06:39 ; 29 ; etc
```

I need to get the date removed so that in "Time" there is only the variable of time (ie. I don't need the system to look at the date at all as it is rather irrelevant).

How would I go about this? And is it reproducible for around 5000 bits of data?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have really the spaces  like this "something ; something" or not like this "something;something"

Comment: I just space separated the ; as that's what I've been taught. The bit I need to remove is the date and/or ignore this (or try to make it a new column with the spaces). Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after seperating the line with ';', just split each part again after each ' '.

```
datetime = "04-09-2003 17:06:39"
parts = datetime.split(' ')
print(parts[1])
```

Comment: That seems to have worked :) thank you :)

Comment: perfect :) You should consider to do some validation before accessing the value of the array, in case the input of the csv file in this column is corrupted or wrong